# How to get xslReportBuildPlugin to work on CruiseControl.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm using CC 1.5.6804.1 and i created and custom xslt file generate a custome report.
I added the file to the xsl directory.
I have also updated the dashboard.config file with the following:

[my additions]

I see no link on the web dashboard after saving and restarting the server.

Has anyone seen this and/or have any ideals??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1/ in the Dashboard, check that you have added the report correctly.

```
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="MyPLugin detail" actionName="MyPLuginDetail" xslFileName="xsl\MyPLuginDetail.xsl">
    <includedProjects>
      <projectName>MyProjectToUseWithThePlugin</projectName>
    </includedProjects>
  </xslReportBuildPlugin>
```

2/ Restart ccnet service or applciation (on the server side).

3/ If you use I2S, you may need to restart I2S services ... with apache, there is no issue about it.

Comment: Thanks.. my problems was that the <xslReportBuildPlugin.....> was in the wrong location.

Comment: yeah, you must add it inside the <buildPlugins> tag.

Comment: @rsbarro Nice to see it can help after many years! That's the power of SO :)

Comment: @TridenT I know, this site is great!